# Test $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4^{n}}\right)}{\sqrt[5]{2 n^{5}-1}} $ for convegence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Tried to identify whether the next sum converges

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\displaystyle \frac{ \displaystyle \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4^{n}}\right)}{\displaystyle \sqrt[\displaystyle 5]{2 \displaystyle n^{5}-1}}
\end{equation}

I used Cauchy test,  $C = 1,$ and also found that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$.

I still cannot conclude nothing with that information.

I need a hint.

Comment: What the first value of $n$?

Comment: try limit test with 1/n.

Comment: @ahala Thanks for the hint. I solved it.